# Extracting .pst file to msg but not getting exact number of msg file

Tags: java, aspose

I am trying to extract pst file into msg.
I am using aspose jar. I share my code where we get exact number of file in each subfolder.

```
public static void displayFolderAndMessageInformationForPSTFile(String dataDir) {

    // Load the Outlook PST file
    PersonalStorage pst = PersonalStorage.fromFile(dataDir + "allen.pst");

    // Get the folders information
    FolderInfoCollection folderInfoCollection = pst.getRootFolder().getSubFolders();

    // Browse through each folder to display folder name and number of messages
    for (int i = 0; i < folderInfoCollection.size(); i++) {
        FolderInfo folderInfo = (FolderInfo) folderInfoCollection.get_Item(i);
        System.out.println("FolderId: " + folderInfo.getEntryIdString());
        System.out.println("Folder: " + folderInfo.getDisplayName());
        System.out.println("Total items: " + folderInfo.getContentCount());
        System.out.println("Total unread items: " + folderInfo.getContentUnreadCount());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
    }
}
```

FolderId: AAAAAJJu05VTxVRJlC5mJefQvVeCgAAA
Folder: Inbox
Total items: 66
Total unread items: 0

But when extract message content then i get different number of msg. It give only 49 msg in inbox folder.
The following below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String pstFileName = dataDir + "allen.pst";
    // Load the Outlook PST file
    PersonalStorage pst = PersonalStorage.fromFile(pstFileName);

    // Get the folders and messages information
    FolderInfo folderInfo = pst.getRootFolder();

    // Create a folder for this PST
    String strRootFolderName = "allen.pst".replace(".pst", "") + ".Java";
    new File(dataDir + strRootFolderName).mkdir();

    // Call the recursive method to extract msg files from each folder
    extractMsgFiles(folderInfo, pst, dataDir + strRootFolderName);

}

private static void extractMsgFiles(FolderInfo folderInfo, PersonalStorage pst, String strPSTFile) {

    // Display the folder name
    System.out.println("Folder: " + folderInfo.getDisplayName());

    // Create folder to store the messages
    String folderName = strPSTFile + "\\" + folderInfo.getDisplayName();
    new File(folderName).mkdir();

    // Loop through all the messages in this folder
    MessageInfoCollection messageInfoCollection = folderInfo.getContents();

    for (int i = 0; i < messageInfoCollection.size(); i++) {
        MessageInfo messageInfo = (MessageInfo) messageInfoCollection.get_Item(i);
        System.out.println("Saving message " + messageInfo.getSubject() + "....");
        // Get the message in MapiMessage instance
        MapiMessage message = pst.extractMessage(messageInfo);

        // Delete special characters which are invalid to use as windows file name
        String messageName = null;
        if (message.getSubject() == null || message.getSubject().isEmpty() == true) {
            messageName = getRidOfIllegalFileNameCharacters(messageInfo.getEntryIdString());
        } else {
            messageName = getRidOfIllegalFileNameCharacters(message.getSubject());
        }

        // Save this message to disk in MSG format
        message.save(folderName + "\\" + messageName + ".msg");
    }

    // Call this method recursively for each subfolder
    if (folderInfo.hasSubFolders() == true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < folderInfo.getSubFolders().size(); i++) {
            FolderInfo subfolderInfo = (FolderInfo) folderInfo.getSubFolders().get_Item(i);
            extractMsgFiles(subfolderInfo, pst, strPSTFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Help me... Where did i make mistake ?  I am new in Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the following code snippet for extracting message files. You may use this method in place of your **extractMsgFiles** method.

```
private static void ExtractMsgFiles(FolderInfo folderInfo, PersonalStorage pst)
{

    // display the folder name
    Console.WriteLine("Folder: " + folderInfo.DisplayName);
    Console.WriteLine("==================================");

    // loop through all the messages in this folder
    MessageInfoCollection messageInfoCollection = folderInfo.GetContents();

    foreach (MessageInfo messageInfo in messageInfoCollection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Saving message {0} ....", messageInfo.Subject);

        // get the message in MapiMessage instance
        MapiMessage message = pst.ExtractMessage(messageInfo);

        // save this message to disk in msg format
        message.Save(message.Subject.Replace(":", " ") + ".msg");

        // save this message to stream in msg format
        MemoryStream messageStream = new MemoryStream();

        message.Save(messageStream);
    }

    // Call this method recursively for each subfolder
    if (folderInfo.HasSubFolders == true)
    {
        foreach (FolderInfo subfolderInfo in folderInfo.GetSubFolders())
        {
            ExtractMsgFiles(subfolderInfo, pst);
        }
    }
}
```

You may visit the link [Working with Messages in a PST File](https://docs.aspose.com/display/emailnet/Working+with+Messages+in+a+PST+File) in case you are interested in more details.
I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: i use this ExtractMsgFiles method, but still i didn't get extact number of msg. Again it show 49 msg in Inbox folder.

Comment: @Ashish, you can share your sample PST file on [Aspose.Email support forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/email) so that it can be further investigated.

Answer (score 0):

The emails not having unique subject names could be causing this issue? I had this exact issue when doing something similar in Powershell. Putting an autonumber in the filename could help get around this.